# Why Variations of order higher than two vanish for Brownian motion?

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $W_{t}$ be a Brownian Motion.  Verify that variations of Brownian Motion of higher order, say, of order three, vanishes. I try to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{n}_{i=1}(W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}})^{3}=0$ but I have trouble continuing the step. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the convergence is in probability and the partition $\Pi_n$ is given by
\begin{align*}
0=t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = t.
\end{align*}
Note that
$$\mathbb{E}\big((W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3 \big)=0,$$ and $$\mathbb{E}\big((W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^6 \big)=15(t_i-t_{i-1})^3.$$
Let $\|\Pi_n\| = \max_{i=1}^n|t_i-t_{i-1}|$.
Then, for any small $\delta>0$, by Chebyshev inequality,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\Big(\Big|\sum_{i=1}^n (W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3\Big| > \delta \Big)& \leq \frac{1}{\delta^2}\mathbb{E}\bigg(\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n (W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3\Big)^2\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{\delta^2}\mathbb{E}\bigg( \sum_{i,j=1}^n (W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3(W_{t_j}-W_{t_{j-1}})^3\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{\delta^2}\mathbb{E}\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n (W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^6\Big)\\
&=\frac{15}{\delta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (t_i-t_{i-1})^3\\
&\leq  \frac{15\, t}{\delta^2}\|\Pi_n\|^2.
\end{align*}
That is,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\Big(\Big|\sum_{i=1}^n (W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3\Big| > \delta \Big) = 0.$$
Therefore, for any $t>0$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3 = 0$$
in probability.